# ZipArchive not working for Universal App (Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1)

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Hi i have this problem in ZipArchive for my universal app. The code below works fine for the Windows Phone but not for the Windows 8.1 app.

I can'nt see why this is not working for the Windows 8.1 app, but only for the Windows Phone

The Exception i get is this: "Number of entries expected in End Of Central Directory does not correspond to number of entries in Central Directory." when i try to read the entries.

```
        using (var zipStream = await folder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(filename))
        {
            using (MemoryStream zipMemoryStream = new MemoryStream((int)zipStream.Length))
            {
                await zipStream.CopyToAsync(zipMemoryStream);

                using (var archive = new ZipArchive(zipMemoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // THIS CAUSE THE EXCEPTION!!!!
                        foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
                        {

                            if (entry.Name == "")
                            {
                                // Folder
                                await CreateRecursiveFolder(folder, entry);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // File
                                await ExtractFile(folder, entry);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        //throw;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the foreach loop causes the exception? I'd say it's somewhere inside the `CreateRecursiveFolder` or `ÈxtractFile` method and the exceptions just bubble up as these methods are async.

Comment: Yes, first hit cause the exception! I think it is a bug in the framework for Windows 8.1. The same file works when run the it as a Windows Phone app!

Comment: I can't explain why this works on Phone and not RT. But did you try adding `zipMemoryStream.Position = 0;` after the data's copied to the memory stream? Maybe the Phone implementation of ZipArchive seeks as needed but RT's version doesn't? (I assume that you are using _exactly_ the same code in both cases)